# Why is my screen completely black?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While playing Minecraft I wanted to turn command blocks on, so I tested some stuff out.

I looked through the settings and I saw this button about my screen.  It seemed to turn the screen from some kind of format to another. But since then, when it gets to the title screen, everything goes black.  I can get on, I can run it, it will load. I can still click on stuff, log on to servers, and go on single player.

I just don't know what I'm doing, because everything is black...

Does anyone know how to fix this or what exactly I did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll probably want to reset the game. **Warning: If instructions aren't followed correctly, all worlds will be deleted. I am not responsible if this happens.**

1. For Windows 7, press start (on Windows XP click "run..." afterwards and then type in `%appdata%` *in the run dialog, not the search*), type in `%appdata%` in the search bar, and press enter. A folder should pop up.
2. Navigate your way to .minecraft/saves/. Copy everything in that folder to another location. Your desktop, for instance.
3. Now, go back up the folders and delete the .minecraft folder. Empty your recycle bin.
4. Open up the Minecraft Launcher and log in. If you followed directions correctly, it should automatically update.
5. Now, close Minecraft and copy the stuff you copied to your desktop back into .minecraft/saves/
6. Open Minecraft. Enjoy!

If this doesn't work, then there could be something wrong with your video card or drivers.

Comment: its ok if my worlds get deleted, i didnt hav any good world on the computer thats doing it anyway, and thank you thank you. i will try. i will msg u i guess if it works!!